# VB 2010 programs debug not updating

Tags: vb.net, project

In my VisualBasic 2010 When I create a program after the first save it no longer updates.
I can save my work afterward, but it doesn't run that in debug it runs my first save of the file.

I have tried to delete the contents of the debug and this does happen for all of my projects not just the one I have tried searching but when I delete the debug it comes up with errors

Answer (score 0):

If the project won't run after deleting the contents of the 'bin' folder then it appears that your code isn't compiling.  When you try to run and the build fails, you can either stop or run the last successful build.  It sounds like you have told the IDE to just run the last successful build without prompting you.  If that's not what you want then you shouldn't have told it to do so, which you would have had to do.  You can change that in the IDE options.  Open the Errors window and you'll see a list of compilation errors.  Fix them and your project will then build and run.

Comment: I have no problems in the code I have made sure of that and it doesn't work

Comment: So, if you fix all your compilation errors, delete the bin folder and then build, what EXACTLY happens?